# Помогите разобраться в mysql

Tags: mysql

Написать запрос для выбора среднего возраста всех учителей с зарплатой более 10 000

```
select name, age, AVG(age), salary teachers from Teachers order by salary>10000
```

в выводе даёт средний возраст(правильный), и лишь одного человека

Comment: переведите дословно `order by salary > 1000` ? подумайте чем сортировка данных отличается от фильтрации. почитайте про `group by`

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
select avg(age)        -- среднее значение возраста
  from Teachers        -- учителей
 where salary > 10000; -- с зарплатой более 10.000
```